# Express res.download() doesn't trigger a download in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to download a file with res.download but it doesn't trigger a browser download however it send the file data to the console, how can I trigger a browser download?

```
router.get('/downloadFile/:clientId/:item', auth, async (req, res) => {
  const { clientId, item } = req.params;
  const dir = `./public/uploads/${clientId}`;
  const file = `${dir}/${item}`;

  res.download(file, item, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send('There was a problem with download');
    } else {
      return res.send('Download succesful!');
    }
  });
});
```

The action to tigger the download

```
export const downloadFile = (clientId, item) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`api/pdf/downloadFile/${clientId}/${item}`);
    console.log(res.data);
    dispatch({
      type: DOWNLOAD_FILE
      //   payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You just cannot trigger a file download directly via code. Instead, the browser itself needs to be redirected / called with the download url directly, e.g. using `window.location.href=\`api/pdf/downloadFile/${clientId}/${item}\``

Comment: Thanks for the reply, where should I put that code?

Comment: I'd say it would fit into the downloadFile method you posted here.

Comment: but `api/pdf/downloadFile/${clientId}/${item}` is an API call, it's not the location of the file.

Comment: in case of `res.download()` the call to the API will trigger a file download automatically if used as a browser URL instead of an Ajax call